# Intuition of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$?

Tags: improper-integrals

What's the intuition of the improper integral

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$$

Is it really **integral over the entire domain** $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Short answer: yes.

Comment: In fact, It is a notation for a special limit 

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \equiv \lim_{x \to \infty} \int_{-x}^{x}$$

Comment: @H.R. Actually, no. That is a Cauchy principal value. In fact, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty = \lim_{x,y\to\infty} \int_{-x}^y$.

Comment: @H.R. for example, $f(x) = x$ is not considered to have an integral of $0$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Oh, thanks. You mean that this limit for any odd function won't be zero! So, the definition by Ted Shifrin is considered to be true. However, it seems to be a matter of definition and notation. :)

Comment: @H.R.: For the integral over all of $\Bbb R$ to exist, the double-limit I wrote down MUST exist.

Comment: This makes no sense, it's wildly divergent. Where's the $dx$ or $f(x)$ even? ;)

Comment: @TedShifrin: Yeah, I got you Ted. :) Thanks for getting me out of the well! :) And what would be the thing that I wrote down? :)

Comment: @H.R. See [CPV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Many Thanks. :)

Comment: @Zach466920 $f \equiv 0$ ;)

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx$$

Pick any $a \in \mathbb R$.

$$= \int_{-\infty}^{a} f(x) dx + \int_{a}^{\infty} f(x) dx$$

$$= \lim_{b \to -\infty} \int_{b}^{a} f(x) dx + \lim_{c \to \infty} \int_{a}^{c} f(x) dx$$

$$= \lim_{b \to -\infty} [F(a) - F(b)] + \lim_{c \to \infty} [F(c) - F(a)]$$

$$= \lim_{b \to -\infty} [- F(b)] + \lim_{c \to \infty} [F(c)]$$

We can see that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx \ \text{exists if and only if}$$

$$\lim_{b \to -\infty} [- F(b)] \ \text{and} \ \lim_{c \to \infty} [F(c)] \ \text{exist}$$